# Django get_or_create method doesn't return exact object

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In django `manage.py shell`:

```
>>> a,b = Foo.objects.get_or_create(name='hi')
>>> b
True
>>> vars(a)
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x02761390>, 'id': None,
'name': 'hi'}
```

The problem here is the customized `id` attribute has no value. And if I continue to do the following:

```
>>> c = foo.objects.get(name='hi')
>>> c.id
1
>>> a is c
False
```

So that newly created object (denoted by `c`) already exists now, but `b` is not an exact reference to it like `c` is.

Is this a bug? My django version is 1.6.5.

Comment: Why are you comparing `b` with `c`?
`b` is the boolean "created", returned by `get_or_create`, `c` is the object.

Comment: @coldmind Sorry for that. Just corrected it and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, if you have not specified the `id` field for you model, [Django will create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) AutoField:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

In your case you've created just `IntegerField`. I suppose this is the point. In the database, it will still be incremented, but django won't assign the `id` value from database to the object, returned by `get_or_create`

By the way, in your question:

```
>>> b is c
False
```

`b` - is a bool value. I think you were trying to do

```
>>> a is c
```

But also this is not a good idea. If you want to compare django model objects, use `==`, not `is`:

```
>>> a == c
```

You will get `False` anyway, as `a` has its `id` set to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your id field as an IntegerField, so Django does not know it needs to autoincrement. You could define it as an AutoField, but actually there is no reason to declare it at all: Django will automatically define it for you if you leave it out.

Note this has nothing to do with `get_or_create`: you would have exactly the same problem with a normal create/save.

Comment: What does it mean by **does not know it needs to autoincrement**? I still get `c.id == 1`.

Comment: try to use the same model without the id field. (it is created automagically!)